# Why does mdframed "hidealllines" actually show all lines?

Tags: mdframed

I'm trying to use the `hidealllines` key for mdframed, but it's not working, either as a local argument or in an `\mdfsetup`.
It works when I set all the `topline=false`, etc., but not when I just use `hidealllines`—and, furthermore, `hidealllines` seems to *undo* the hiding if each line is explicityly hidden!

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[tikz]{mdframed}

\begin{document}

\mdfsetup{backgroundcolor=blue!10}

% all lines, as expected
\begin{mdframed}
  Text.
\end{mdframed}

% all lines (huh?)
\begin{mdframed}[hidealllines]
  Text.
\end{mdframed}

% no lines, as expected
\begin{mdframed}[topline=false,rightline=false,bottomline=false,leftline=false]
  Text.
\end{mdframed}

% all lines (huh??!)
\begin{mdframed}[topline=false,rightline=false,bottomline=false,leftline=false,hidealllines]
  Text.
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although this isn't stated in the documentation, you have to explicitly set  `hidealllines=true`, not simply `hidealllines`. (The documentation examples do use this, but the key description just says that "you can use the short form `hidealllines`.")

A corrected MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed} % works with tikz/pstricks as well

\begin{document}

\mdfsetup{backgroundcolor=blue!10}

\begin{mdframed}[hidealllines]
  Lines are not hidden.
\end{mdframed}

\begin{mdframed}[hidealllines=true]
  Lines are hidden.
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Output from the above MWE.]